# calling clean() doesn't check the required fields and throws error in admin panel. however its validates the required fields when i remove clean()

Tags: django, django-models

This is my models.py, i am trying to call save function to create brand code and also checking the parent category of sub category should belongs to its original parent category not the other category. please help me out.

```
class Brand(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='category', limit_choices_to={'parent_category__isnull': True})
    sub_category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='sub_category', limit_choices_to={'parent_category__isnull': False})
    brand_code = models.CharField(max_length=70, null=True, blank=True)
    brand_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.brand_name

    def create_brand_code(self):
        pass

    def clean(self):
        if not self.sub_category.parent_category == self.category:
            raise ValidationError("{} is not the sub category of {}".format(self.sub_category, self.category))

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.brand_code:
            if self.sub_category.parent_category == self.category:
                self.brand_code = self.create_brand_code()
                super(Brand, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I've understood your problem correctly, but it looks like you need to check that the foreign keys are set before you access them:

```
def clean(self):
    if self.sub_category_id and self.category_id:
        if not self.sub_category.parent_category == self.category:
             raise ValidationError(...)
```